# Intermediate Value Theorem (Application)

Tags: real-analysis

How would I use the IVT to show that for every continuous function $f : [1,2] \rightarrow [\frac{1}{2}, 1]$ there is some $x \in [1,2]$ with $xf(x) = 1$?

Usually when I have to show things like this I say
"Consider $g(x) = xf(x) -1$" and then show $0 \in [g(1), g(2)]$ so the result follows from the IVT, but I can't get it to work here and I can't think of any modifications I can make to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track. Look at 
$$
g(1) = 1 f(1) -1.
$$
Since $f(1)$ is between 1/2 and 1, $f(1) -1$ is $\le 0$.

Now look at $g(2)$...that's greater than or equal to $0$ by a similar argument. And you're on your way!

Comment: Oh wow, cleared everything right up.
Thanks!